# python Identify raw or string and convert it to another

Tags: python, arrays, string

```
commands = result[0]
for command in commands:

    print(command)
```

and my result are:

```
create vlan,1,vlan switch
enable
configure terminal
vlan 1
name vlan
```

Am I returning a row (array)?
And how to convert it to string?

Comment: Try replacing `print(command)` with `print(type(command))` and you'll see what you have.

Comment: It is a string. Thank you

Comment: Converting it to a string would just be `str(command)`.

Comment: if it's a `string` already, then what is your question?

Comment: and what do you mean "am i returning a row (array)?"  you're not calling a function in the code you posted, so you're not *returning* anything.